# When does the public beta open?

Tags: discussion, beta

Area51 had this very nice minute-by-minute countdown, and now it just says "soon" -- any idea when the public beta actually starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I guess : http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/55368732003942400 ;)